# Leopard Server (10.5.8) Screen Sharing with Open Directory Authentication

Tags: mac-osx, remote-desktop, mac-osx-server, opendirectory, osx-leopard

I have an OS X 10.5.8 Leopard Server that I manage here in the office.  Right now it has just the standard VNC single password style of authentication for authenticating for screen sharing.  Our usernames and passwords are all managed through Leopard Server's Open Directory.  Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to get Screen Sharing to lookup users in the Open Directory for authentication.  It will only authenticate against normal local user accounts on the machine.  What I'd ideally like is for screen sharing to look up the user in the directory.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same thing on Apple's discussion forums and received an answer there.  I'm posting it here in case anyone else runs into this and looks here.

From Jason Agress:

> If you have access to Apple Remote
>   Desktop, you can create a custom
>   Client Installer that sets a machine
>   to use directory-based authentication.
>   However, if you don't have it, you
>   should be able to use the script I've
>   pasted below. Once you've done this,
>   you will need to create Open Directory
>   groups that correspond to the amount
>   of access you want a given user to
>   have (ard_admin, ard_reports,
>   ard_manage, ard_interact) and add
>   users to the appropriate groups.

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -clientopts -setdirlogins -dirlogins yes

sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -restart -agent -console
```